# Sprites aren't showing up on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, sprite, sprite-sheet, moovweb

I am testing my Moovweb project on both an iPhone and an iOS stimulator and I don't see the images from my sprite folder.

Going through the motions...

1) Line near the top of main.scss: @import "globals/_sprites";

2) I'm following the recommended syntax in the header.ts file:

$("//div[@id='SearchForm']/form//input[@type='image']") {
  wrap("div", class: "mv_search_btn sprites-search")
  attribute("style", "opacity:0;")
}

3) They are in their own divs

So what gives?? Why can I see on other testing machines but not on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

Doh! I figured it out - the image size was too large.

Apple recommends that images for iPhone be no larger than 1024x1024 pixels. If you have a very large sprite sheet (over these dimensions), the sprites will not display on an iPhone (or an iOS simulator), even though they may work on Chrome, for example.

To solve this problem, you should split the images that need to be sprited into multiple folders and use multiple sprite sheets.